# consistencies in closures

Tags: discussion

I just got an accept from an older question :[What is a good definition of 'time'? [duplicate]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156132/what-is-a-good-definition-of-time/156180#156180)

Curious I went to the duplicate,[Time, what is it? [closed]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17056/time-what-is-it), and see that it is closed with the explanation:

*As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*

There is a logical inconsistency here of pointing to a duplicate that is closed with such a reason. Either the original should have been closed or it should not have been marked duplicate.

Edit after I read the comments that led to the duplicate assignment. The second link provided in QMECHANIC's comment is fine and should be subsituted

Comment: Why is it inconsistent? If the question has been asked before, it's a duplicate, so closing it as duplicate is as valid as closing it for the reason the original was closed.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Supposedly we are not setting up a game but a resource searchable and referable that would help in understanding physics. Pointless  pointers are useless. anyway see my edit

Comment: I see your point (and I agree).

Comment: I am not sure that I see an issue with pointing out that the newer question is a duplicate of an older bad question. Sure a "duplicate of a duplicate of a Q" ought to cut out the middle-man, but a "duplicate of an off-topic question" doesn't seem bad or pointless to me.

Comment: @KyleKanos: The duplicate text says: *"This question already has an answer here"*. While technically true for this particular example, that's not really what we want to convey if the original has been declared off-topic, right? Pointing out the duplicate is ok, closing as duplicate and not off-topic seems indeed inconsistent.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Can topics be closed for more than one reason?

Comment: @StanShunpike: It's closed if five close votes are cast, no matter for which reason, but only the majority close reason is displayed (this has created annoyance before).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Why? I guess it is hard to follow rules if they aren't applied consistently. I feel like this sometimes when posting on different stack exchanges.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I don't really see any inconsistency. It's a question that was already asked, ergo it's a duplicate. Both questions happen to be off-topic because they're a bad questions. Either way, the newer one *should* be closed & any way it happens is fine.

Comment: @KyleKanos: As annav said, it's not a game of "Find a valid close reason", but we're creating a physics Q&A database. Closing a question with the message *"This question already has an answer here"* somewhat implies that this is a physics question that just happens to already exist within the database, and only when you click the link (or know SE and notice the *[closed]*) you'll discover that we don't actually consider that question physics. It's a totally pointless click that conveys no useful information whatsoever.

Comment: If it's a bad question, close it for being a bad question (whatever that close reason may be). I think "duplicate" should be used for "On topic question that has been asked and answered before."

Comment: @tpg2114 make it a short answer and I will choose it

Comment: @ACuriousMind: See my answer as to why I still see no inconsistency.

Comment: @annav I see closing a question A as duplicate of question B as saying something on the lines of *this matter has already been discussed in B*. If B has been closed for some reason, then we are saying *we already discussed this matter in B, and we decided that it is off-topic on this site for such and such reasons*. But what if in some time in the future the policies change and B is no longer considered off-topic? If all the duplicates have been closed as dups of B, then we'll only have to reopen B, otherwise we'll have to reopen B, and then change the reason for closure of all the dups of B.

Comment: @glance Physics does not change so fast, and I do not expect this site to be a resource for the curious in fifty years. A spade should be called a spade, if it is off topic, off topic, not pointed to off topic. In any case the above example as my edit shows had a good duplicate to point to, which means that people with the power to make duplicates sometimes do not even read further than the title they tie to duplication.

Comment: @annav in this case of course the best thing is to point to the "good" duplicate I don't argue with that. But I'd say that the policies can change way faster than the physics, and given for example all the continuous debates over the homework policies changes do not seem so unlikely even on the short period. And given the fast growing pace of the stackexchange network, in the fifty years period this may be an awesome place containing huge amounts of perfectly indexed (maybe we'll manage to that in fifty years) information. Or maybe not, but it would be awesome if that were the case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we should strive to choose the most appropriate/specific close reasons when we vote to close. It is extra important in cases like this because the duplicate question close message encourages users to ask a new question if the answers on the duplicate don't address their specific concerns. But we don't want somebody to ask a new question about something that is off-topic to begin with.

To ensure consistency and to avoid problems like this, the process of reviewing a question should be something along the lines of:

1. Evaluate whether the question is on- or off-topic. If it is off-topic, **vote to close** based on the most appropriate off-topic close reason.
2. If the question is on-topic, look at the content of the question:

   - Has the question been asked before? Many times, I can find a duplicate in the "Related questions" bar on the right side. If I can't find it there, and I think "Surely this is something I've seen before" or "There's no way this hasn't been asked before," I'll search for possible duplicates. If a possible duplicate is found, **vote to close as a duplicate** and move to the next question. If no duplicate is found, continue.
   - Does the question show research effort, is it clear and useful? **Upvote**.
   - If it is on-topic but just a bad question (not useful to anybody else, no research, etc.) -- **downvote** and move on to the next question.

If we follow that type of flow, we would avoid situations when we say "Hey User, your question already has an answer! Oh wait, but we closed it because it's off-topic..." Instead, we just say "This is off-topic because X" and it doesn't matter if it's been asked 100 times before.

I know some may disagree on the whole upvote/downvote thing. But regardless of your views on that, I think it makes the most sense to decide if something is on-topic before looking for potential duplicates. It seems silly to chase down potential duplicates to off-topic questions (wastes our time) and it also presents a strange message to people not familiar with how our site, or StackExchange in general, works.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with the "inconsistency" as viewed by some is the fact that **close states are not permanent**, yet they are being viewed as a permanent state. This is simply not true; any post can be re-opened at any time. In light of this point of view, it should be clear that there isn't any inconsistency.

Note that close states also do **not** at all suggest that the question itself is "not physics." What it *does* suggest is that the question does not *fit the site* in its **current form** under **current policies**. A closed question may be a perfectly valid physics question; case in point: homework questions. We view these as off-topic, even though they certainly are valid physics questions. And since policies can change, there is no reason to suspect that an off-topic question will remain closed.

<sup>I do note though that, on occasion, there are questions asked here that aren't actually physics (e.g., some people asking engineering, philosophy or chemistry questions). This does not mean that the close state *itself* indicates that the question is not physics.</sup>

This also has been discussed on Mother Meta before:

- [What should I do with a question that has an exact duplicate closed as off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173431/what-should-i-do-with-a-question-that-has-an-exact-duplicate-closed-as-off-topic)
- [Can we prevent questions from being closed as duplicates of closed questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186706/can-we-prevent-questions-from-being-closed-as-duplicates-of-closed-questions)
- [Should duplicates of closed questions be closed as duplicates or closed for the same reason as their parent question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115125/should-duplicates-of-closed-questions-be-closed-as-duplicates-or-closed-for-the)

The solution is mixed between the answers (so obviously no consensus, not even highly upvoted answers), but two points were brought up there that we ought to consider:

1. What happens if we later decide that the closed-original is on-topic?
2. What happens if we later decide that an unclosed-original is off-topic? What should we do to the questions closed as duplicate of *that* one?

In the first case, your issue disappears because the close-state isn't permanent. This should suggest that closing as a duplicate of a closed question should not present any problems/inconsistencies because of the fact that the original can be reopened.

In the second case, we have the opposite case you present. Should we then go through all the duplicates and re-label them as off-topic? That would be quite a lot of *unnecessary* work (because it brings us right back to (1)).

I disagree with [tgp2114's evaluation process](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6565/25301); the reasoning should be in this order:

1. Has the question been asked before?

   - Close as duplicate
2. Is the question off-topic (HW, engineering, etc)? Too broad? Opinion based?

   - Close appropriately
3. Can't tell *or* disagree

   - Skip *or* Leave Open

It should not matter if the proposed duplicate is also closed as off-topic because, again, it can get out of that state.

Comment: Alright, *technically*, it presents less of an issue to close stuff as duplicates. *Practically*, closing off-topic stuff sends a message that we don't want to send, again, *"This question already has an answer here"*. I don't think your formal argument trumps the actual *meaning* of the duplicate closure, but I'd say it's really a matter of opinion. Let the votes decide (and perhaps annav could unaccept the answer until some time has passed?).

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Since originals are required to have an answer in order to select it for dupes, the statement **is** indeed correct: the question does have an answer.

Comment: I didn't say it sends an *incorrect message*, I said it sends a message we *don't want to send*. That off-topic questions here sometimes receive, for better or worse, answers, is not something I really wish to advertise.

Comment: I will repeat that this is not a site set up as a game plan. At least I hope that the aim is to offer a useful  physics resource and a recourse for somebody looking at  the topic. In this case  somebody looking for "a definition of time" finds a duplicate label, goes to the dublicate and discovers it is off topic. Has she/he learned anything except not to value physics.se?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: You're still thinking of it as the original question being *permanently* closed. This is not true.

Comment: @annav: Who says it is a game plan? I certainly never said it, and I certainly never implied it either. I'm stating that closing questions as duplicates of other closed questions *is not a problem*. Since duplicates require the original to have an answer, they'd still get "an" answer by going to the original. It may not be *canonical*, but it might also suggest to them that their question *is ill-defined*.

Comment: So I would say, *Yes, absolutely they get something out of their experience in following the Rabbit Hole*.

Comment: sent to a question that is off topic invalidates the answers in that question and makes the whole thing nonsense

Comment: if the new question is off topic for physis se, just close it, instead of a run around.

Comment: @annav: How does a question closed as Off-topicn invalidate any answers therein? *That* is nonsense. Consider the HW questions we have. Are the answers to those questions invalid because the HW Q is closed as off-topic? No, certainly not. Just as in this case as well.

Comment: lets agree to disagree